Javascript function not returning value when working with blazor and JSInterop
I am trying to run javascript code through C#. I am using JSInterop to call javascript function from C#. I have installed metammask sdk and then trying to get the account after connecting.
window.getAccount = async function () {
    try {
        const accounts = await provider.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        console.log("accounts = ", accounts);
        if (accounts.length != 0 || accounts != undefined) { 
            console.log("accounts = ", accounts);
            console.log("account[0] = ", accounts[0]);
            return accounts[0]; // Return the first account
        }
        else
            return "new error"
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 4001) {
            console.log("Please connect to MetaMask.");
            return "Allow to connect to Metamask"; // Return a message indicating to connect to MetaMask
        } else {
            console.error(err);
            throw err; // Re-throw the error
            return " error ..."
        }
    }
}

The above is my javascript code. Here i am returning the account if the user accepts the connecting request and returning a message if he rejects.
I am calling this function from the cs file like
        string output = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getAccount");

        Console.WriteLine("output = ",  output);

The issue:

When I am rejecting the connection request the message "Please connect to metamask" gets consoled but after that an error occurs : crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at window.getAccount (https://localhost:57476/js/index.bundle.js:1:483)
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at window.getAccount (https://localhost:57476/js/index.bundle.js:1:483)
at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.d__16`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib,

stating that I am trying to access the 0 index of an undefined object (most probably accounts).

When I am accepting the request then nothing/empty string is returned.

I tried changing the structure of the getAccount funtion hoping the return statement miht work, but no progress.
Expected result: The account should be returned if the user accepts the connect request and if the user rejects the connect the error message should be returned.

What does your provider.request method code look like? Can you post that? What do your console.log calls output in both valid and invalid results scenarios?

The problem is solved, actually my browser cache was not cleared and was invoking the wrong code
